# Two vowels together: "Go out" and "Go upstairs"

Tags: verbs, pronunciation, phonetics, phonology

Is go outside correct? and also "go upstairs.". Since two vowels are followed by each other, eg., o then after this it's o again. How is that?

Comment: If you mean the rule applied to indefinite articles, it doesn't affect all situations... otherwise, you couldn't even say "y**ou a**re" or "t**oo o**ld"

Comment: All the following are are correct: go out, go outside, go on, go over, go upstairs, go up, go in, go away.........I don't really understand your question.

Comment: @User1 - They aren't saying it's incorrect, they're asking how such a case is handled verbally: many languages do not have this situation such as this where two similar/identical sounds follow each other. Perhaps Araucaria's answer will help you understand what the question meant.

Answer (score 10):

The word "go" has a vowel that ends in the sound [ʊ]. When words that end in this sound are followed by another vowel, we like to put a small /w/ sound in between to separate out the two vowel sounds. So for "go outside" or "go upstairs", you will probably hear a native speaker say something like "go woutside" and "go wupstairs".

There is no problem in English when we use a  word ending in a vowel and another one beginning with a vowel, but speakers often like to separate the two words by inserting a consonant. We usually use /w/, /j/ or a glottal stop, /ʔ/. People who speak non-rhotic English (where we don't pronounce /r/ at the end of a syllable), sometimes use an /r/ sound. There are different rules for which consonant to use depending on the quality of the first vowel.

Comment: _"... but speakers often like to separate the two words by inserting a consonant._"  Or a *very* brief pause to create separation _"The bear wanted to go_ [!] _over the hill."_  (PacNW, USA)

Comment: @Adam: Often what appears to be a "very brief pause" is in fact a glottal stop...

Comment: If it is a glottal stop between _go_ and _over,_ it is a much more subtle one that what I produce in _Uh-Oh._ ...I think I exhale constantly, but I can't be sure..... My neighbors in the office think I am nuts now because I keep mumbling about bear migration, literally just to hear myself talk..

Answer (score 7):

The indefinite articles ("a" and "an") are the *only* words in English that require any special written treatment based on the following word's first sound (usually based on the first letter).

Occasionally it sounds better to avoid consecutive vowel strings if they make words too hard to distinguish, but there's no formal rule for that, and it's usually easy enough to pronounce words separately in speech. In writing there is no such problem.

Comment: That's not quite accurate. For speakers of non-rhotic Englishes a word ending in orthographic 'r' will be pronounced with an /r/ sound infront of a vowel, but otherwise will have no /r/ sound. Additionally, many function words will have completely different pronunciations depending on whether they are followed by a vowel or not. So for example the word *the* is usually /ði/ in front of vowels and  /ðə/ otherwise. Likewise with the word *to*, which will be /tu/ in fornt of vowels, but /tə/ otherwise.

Comment: In the interest of excellent (and not misleading) answers, these rules (apart from a few old-fashioned affected 'h' fads for poor speakers) don't have anything to do with letters at all -  only sounds. Secondly, there are no words that are difficult to distinguish because of consecutive vowels. strings.

Comment: @Araucaria: That's an odd way to put it, since the rules undeniably *do* have to do with letters: a/an are written with a letter different. If you mean that the following first letter can occasionally be a silent letter that would otherwise be a consonant, that's true, but not contradicted; it's not a major aspect of the question so I didn't spell all that out.

Comment: Hmmm. Your post only talks about *subsequent* letters. In any case, that's not at all correct. The words *a/an* only change according to the following words' *sounds*, not their letters. So if the sound is a vowel sound we need *an* regardless of the spelling, and if the following sound is a consonant sound, we can only have *a* and aren't allowed *an* - even if the actual letter is a vowel.

Comment: @Araucaria: I think you were misreading it a bit, but just in case, I've clarified again.